# Comparing dates with .valueOf

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

Hey I'm struggling treating dates. Hope someone can give a bit of a light so I can proceed.

I get the value of two dates in a certain sheet, but when comparing them, even if they are different, the execution acts like they are the same.

```
var date1 = Sheet1.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
var date2 = Sheet1.getRange(2, 1).getValue(); 
if (date1.valueOf == date2.valueOf) {
    Sheet1.getRange(3, 1).setValue("TRUE");
}
else {Sheet1.getRange(3, 1).setValue("FALSE")};
```

No matter the dates it appears always to be true. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the value at [1,1] & [2,1] in sheet ? Can you show here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code nearly works - valueOf is a function:

```
var date1 = Sheet1.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
var date2 = Sheet1.getRange(2, 1).getValue(); 
if (date1.valueOf() == date2.valueOf()) {
    Sheet1.getRange(3, 1).setValue("TRUE");
}
else {Sheet1.getRange(3, 1).setValue("FALSE")};
```